# Grails 2.1 apps deployment on tomcat cluster

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, cluster-computing

I had build a stand alone application on grails 2.1 which uses quart scheduler.
Now I need to deploy this application on Apache tomcat cluster using mod_jk connector.
I am running multiple instance of tomcat and and using Delta Manager for managing the session, but it's not working as I am able to log in the first tomcat instance deployed apps but when I am trying to log into the second instance ,then it won't fetch user information from database and give message that user name or password incorrect.

Even if I stop the first instance, still it won't let me log into the system. I try to find solution online for this problem but didn't get any information on how to deploy grails 2.1  web application on tomcat cluster using mod_jk connector. All the information is available for grails 1.3 version which is pretty old and not relevant for grails 2.1.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see what would have changed in Grails that would affect this. You're just deploying a war file

Comment: I am using MySQL database and net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory. I have created the ehcache.xml and ecache_distributed.xml but when I create war , I won't find it. Also the script _Events.groovy won't create any mapping. The main problem I am facing is related to login. If I run two different tomcat instance and copy the war in webapps folder then I am able to login in only first instance application. The second instance wont let user login in to the system even if I kill the first instance.

Comment: Also I am using linux server to deploy the application which has database also. I am just storing user id in session so I don't need to serialize the User class.